# Where am I going next?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

[image]I have planned my travel with a theme.

I start in OMAN. Then off to TONGA. Then to MEXICO. Then SAMOA. Then HAITI. Then to my final destination.

What is it?

1  KENYA

2  SRI LANKA

3  MOLDOVA

Which one? Why?

Comment: Does it matter rot13(jurer va gur pbhagel gur neebjf cbvag gb)?

Comment: Yes @xyldke. It does. Abgr gur Pbhagel Anzrf. Gurl ner va hccre pnfr!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your final destination is:

> **Moldova**.

Your rule for planning your route is:

> Select countries whose capitals have the full name of a Greek letter in them, then visit them in the order of the letters in the Greek alphabet. So:
>
>  OMAN    – μ  – **Mu**scat
>  TONGA   – ν  – **Nu**ku'alofa
>  MEXICO  – ξ – Me**xi**co City
>  SAMOA   – π  – A**pi**a
>  HAITI   – τ – Por**t-au**-Prince
>  MOLDOVA – χ – **Chi**sinau
>
>  The blue arrows point to the capitals' locations on the maps and the names of the countries are written in an all-capitals style.

Comment: mine's simpler  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your final destination is

> **Kenya**

because

> you are alternating hemispheres.
>
> Oman (Northern hemisphere)
> Tonga (Southern hemisphere)
> Mexico (Northern hemisphere)
> Samoa (Southern hemisphere)
> Haiti (Northern hemisphere)
> Kenya (in both hemispheres, but you will be visiting the part in the southern hemisphere, perhaps the capital city, Nairobi?)